# Execute commands in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Normally, I will execute the followings:

```
System.out.println("Title DVD 1: " + dvd1.getTitle());
System.out.println("Title DVD 2: " + dvd2.getTitle());
```

Then I will get the titles of DVD 1 and DVD 2. If I want to print 100 titles of DVDs, obviously I need a lot of

```
System.out.println.
```

I managed to get these **System.out.println** in an ArrayList as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> displayDVDList = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( int i = 0; i <= 22; i++) {
    displayDVDList.add("System.out.println(\"Title DVD " + i + " : \" 
        + dvd" + i + ".getTitle());");
    System.out.println(displayDVDList.get(i) + " ");
}
```

However, I cannot execute those **System.out.println** to display the titles. Thus, how to execute a value of ArrayList which happens to be **System.out.println** command?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: OK, for starters, you can't "execute an ArrayList". What are you *actually* trying to (without reference to *how* you're trying to do it)?

Comment: If you add `Objects` to your ArrayList, then after doing a `get` you can `act` on the `Object`  e.g. `ArrayList<DVD> displayDVDList = new ArrayList<DVD>();`

Comment: @Scary Wombat I don't quite understand what you meant by "adding Objects". How to do that?

Comment: I was trying to have a lot of these:

System.out.println("Title DVD 0 : " + dvd0.getTitle()); 
System.out.println("Title DVD 1 : " + dvd1.getTitle()); 
System.out.println("Title DVD 2 : " + dvd2.getTitle()); 
System.out.println("Title DVD 3 : " + dvd3.getTitle()); 
System.out.println("Title DVD 4 : " + dvd4.getTitle());

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the type of `dvd1` and `dvd2` is a class `Dvd` with the `getTitle()` method, your code could be something like the following, where the elements of the list are not `String` values, but `Dvd` objects.

```
// Build list of DVDs
Random random = new Random();
ArrayList<Dvd> displayDVDList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 22; i++) {
    String dvdTitle = "DVD #" + (random.nextInt(1000) + 1);
    displayDVDList.add(new Dvd(dvdTitle));
}

// Print list of DVDs
for (int i = 0; i < displayDVDList.size(); i++) {
    Dvd dvd = displayDVDList.get(i);
    System.out.println("Title DVD " + (i + 1) + ": " + dvd.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: I will have a try. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It half works. Only now I have to think how to add all them up.

Comment: @smalltownstory Maybe what would be even nicer would be to have the `Dvd` themselves have a `print` or `toString` method

Answer (score 0):

> Every answer is helpful and I am adding to it .First Thing to
>   understand is , u want some property of your object to be printed. Use
>   toString() method from object class , as it it created specifically
>   for it . use arrayList.toString() and override toString() in your
>   class.

```
class Person1
{

    String name ;
    String state;
    public Person1(String name, String state) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
    }
    public Person1() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", state=" + state + "]";
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person nitin = new Person("nitin", "delhi");
        Person chandan = new Person("chandan", "delhi");
        Person anshu = new Person("anshu", "bihar");
        Person rahul = new Person("rahul", "bihar");
        Person amar = new Person("nitin", "UP");

    List<Person> peoples = Arrays.asList(nitin,chandan, anshu, rahul,amar);

    System.out.println(peoples);    


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could load everything first and then print with the System.out.println. Java 8 has a way to run using stream. For example:

```
ArrayList<String> displayDVDList = new ArrayList<String>();
displayDVDList.add("Title 1");
displayDVDList.add("Title 2");
displayDVDList.add("Title 3");
displayDVDList.add("Title 4");
displayDVDList.add("Title 5");

displayDVDList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I hope it helps you !

Comment: Thank you. But, this is is the one that I want to avoid. We are not talking about 5 items. Perhaps, hundreds.